# Kerberos, windows authentocation request in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, kerberos

I made a web api with windows authentication in it (using iis as well). I need my client to send an ajax request to that web api but the response is 401 unauthorized.

I think it is because no negotiate headers are sent in the request. But I can't seem to find a way to use negotiage header in the request for the windows authentication to work.

I have been looking a lot and i can't seem to find javascript request with negotiate headers.
Would definetly help to even understand if that is where I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

It will send Negotiate header only if you set `xhr.withCredentials = true` (or `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` if using `$.ajax({...})`).

Comment: Hi, any idea how to get kerberos credentials? I mean the above code will send the credentials, but how to get them from OS or browser ?

Comment: You can't get them from the browser/JavaScript, but from native code you can get a context/identity/ticket. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In my existing application, server sends 401/Negotiate, browser sends kerberos ticket on the request. I want to achieve the same thing inside async javascript request. This is for renewing the krb token for backend jobs. I want it to work without any page refresh or redirection.

Comment: Just setting withCredentials to true as shown in my answer should cause it to include it in the async JavaScript request. From there the URL you request will just have to try and give/replace the current Kerberos ticket/session to your backend job based on a session id or something else unique.

Comment: In that case it will return the same ticket every time. I want it to get its expiry time updated, so backend job can use it further. This renewing is performed by the browser usually. If my current krb ticket (on my desktop) is expired, browser and os will take care of issuing new one or update timestamp of existing when negotiate request comes.